# Reading byte from Output Register of I/O Expander via I2C

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c

The below Arduino code snippet shows a function that should return a **byte read from the Output Register** of an I/O Expander **TCA9535** via **I2C**. I oriented my code at the **TCA9535** Datasheet **Figure 7-8**, seen here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgNAQ.png.

However, calling `readOutputRegister()` always returns `255`.

```
uint8_t readOutputRegister(){

  Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);   // Set Write mode (RW = 0)
  Wire.write(0x02);               // Read-write byte Output Port 0


  // Repeated START
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x21);   // Set Read mode (RW = 1)
  
  uint8_t res = Wire.read();

  // Stop condition
  Wire.endTransmission();
  
  
  return res;
}
```

Here is the link for the datasheet of the **TCA9535** I/O Expander I am using: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9535.pdf

Comment: Maybe the output register contains 255?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I checked it with a multimeter and it contains 0

Comment: Maybe the output pins are active-low?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I Can put anything in. I tried it with 1, 255 and some other numbers that should change it from outputting 255. But sadly nothing changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, from `Wire.endTransmission()` [reference page](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/wire/endtransmission/).

> This function ends a transmission to a peripheral device that was begun by beginTransmission() and **transmits** the bytes that were queued by write().

For Wire library, many people think `Wire.write()` would send the data, it is actually not, it only put the data on a queue. Data will only get send when you call `Wire.endTransmission()`.

So you need to call `Wire.endTransmission()` after `Wire.write(0x02)`.

Secondly, to read the data, it needs to call `Wire.requestFrom()` and also need to check if data has received with `Wire.available()` before reading the data.

```
Wire.beginTransmission(0x20);   // Set Write mode (RW = 0)
Wire.write(0x02);               // Read-write byte Output Port 0
if (Wire.endTransmission() != 0) {
  // error
}
else {
  Wire.requestFrom(0x20, 1); // request 1 byte from the i2c address
  if (Wire.available()) {
     uint8_t c = Wire.read();
  }
}
```